# How To Count Data Row In the table

Tags: ajax, if-statement, delete-row

I Want to Count My data In the table to make a condition, but I have not found for the solution

I've tried to make a `length` in the javascript function but this method still doesn't work and i tried with `size()` but in the web console show error

Javascript Code

```
$('.btn_hapus').on('click', function() {
  var id_form = $('#textkode').val();
  var data_length = $("td").length;
  console.log(data_length);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?= site_url('request/delete') ?>",
     dataType: "JSON",
     data: {
       id_form: id_form
     },
     success: function(data) {
     if (condition) {
        $('#ModalHapus').modal('hide');
        $('#ModalShow').modal('hide');
         $("tr[data-id='" + id_form + "']").fadeOut("fast", function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    load_data();
                }
            }
        });
   return false;
});
```

I expect the data will be count 2, because in my database there are only 2 data, but when i use the `length` in the console result is 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is wrong.

```
var data_length = $("td").length;
```

To fix, do

```
var data_length = $("tr").length;
```

Comment: But the result still not correct, in the console result is 5 but my data is 2 and then when im delete data to 1, the result is 4

Comment: @Alif Depends on the structure of your table. I assumed there's just one table in your page with simple data rows.  If not,  then maybe you have more than one table in the page. Just to be sure,  try giving the table an Id and instead count like this: `var data_length = $('#tblId tr').length`.